# click() function is not being fired if mouse is moved at all

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I'm writing a small script that enables custom hotkeys for a web app I use (https://notion.so). I'm essentially watching for a combination of hotkeys and clicking a particular element using the code below.

The issue i'm having, is the click function only fires when I manually click into the body of the page. If I move my mouse even one bit, it seems focus is lost and therefore the click no longer functions.

I'm using Chrome.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

var newButton = '#notion-app > div > div.notion-cursor-listener > div.notion-frame > div.notion-scroller.vertical.horizontal > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(6) > div';
var searchButton = '#notion-app > div > div.notion-cursor-listener > div.notion-frame > div.notion-scroller.vertical.horizontal > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(4) > div';

window.addEventListener("keydown", keysPressed, false);
window.addEventListener("keyup", keysReleased, false);

var keys = [];

function keysPressed(e) {

// store an entry for every key pressed
keys[e.keyCode] = true;

// Cmd + Alt + N
if (keys[17] && keys[18] && keys[78]) {

    // do something

    document.querySelector(newButton).click();

    // prevent default browser behavior
    e.preventDefault();

}

// Cmd + Alt + S
if (keys[17] && keys[18] && keys[83]) {

    // do something
    document.querySelector(searchButton).click();

    // prevent default browser behavior
    e.preventDefault();

}

}

function keysReleased(e) {
    // mark keys that were released
    keys[e.keyCode] = false;
}

})();
```

Comment: Have you tried simply [setting focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus) (`element.focus()`) to the button prior to clicking it?

Comment: @tim Actually I did try that, but for good measure I tried again. No change. Simply added `document.querySelector(newButton).focus();` prior to the `click()`

Comment: Could be caused by your OS or desktop manager activating other windows on mouse hover, if you enabled such mode.

Comment: @wOxxOm, nothing I am aware of is doing this. I'm on MacOS Mojave, using chrome. I suppose I could try it on a virtual windows machine to be safe...